# How to use this.id in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Instead of assigning variable for this.id, does anyone know the syntax of how would I pass this.id into findIndex function?

```
listing.slideUp(500, function() {
    var listing_id = this.id;
    // I'd like it to say car[0].id == this.id ?
    var index = cars.findIndex(function(car) { return car[0].id === listing_id });
    if (index > -1) {
        cars.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Literally put id inside function(), it'll pass it in, then listing_id replaced with passin var name

Comment: Use an arrow function: `car => car[0].id === this.id`

Comment: Huh? What function? Can you show what you mean?

Comment: ^^^ or use `bind()` on the anonymous method to assign the element as the this

Comment: @Michael https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a browser that does not support arrow functions (`=>`) then an alternative is to bind the `this` to the method.  Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

```js
var object = {
  id: 'c'
};

console.log(
  $('div').filter(
    function(index, element){
      return element.id == this.id;
    }.bind(object)
  ).get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Otherwise you can just us an arrow function, which does not change the context of the `this`.  Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```js
var array = ['a', 'c', 'e'];

$('div').on('click', function(){
  array.forEach(id => {
    if (id == this.id) {
      console.log(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
<div id="d">d</div>
```