# If statement and some() function in JS without arrow syntax

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write this if statement in JS without using arrow syntax?

```
// Arrow Syntax
if (!filters.some(e => e.label === filter_object.label))
{
   // Do Something
}


// ? Not working...
if (!filters.some(function(e) { e.label === filter_object.label }))
{
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: sure, but you'll need a return statement in the function. Arrow functions can do an implicit return if they have just one line and omit the curly brackets, but regular functions require it to be explicit.

Comment: Less than 24 hours ago, you used `function` syntax in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358128/how-to-use-this-id-in-function) with a `return` statement, where the function is passed as a callback. Why would it be suddenly different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `return` statement, because it is a classic function which returns `undefined`, if no different value is specified.

```
if (!filters.some(function(e) { return e.label === filter_object.label; })
//                              ^^^^^^
```